# Codeigniter: How do I pass multiple inputs with multiple same names?

Tags: codeigniter

First off, thank you for your *valuable* time and interest - any input to a beginner is greatly appreciated!

How do I insert multiple inputs with (in most cases) multiple same names? Here is my code:

View:

```
  //Simplified version, original is a jquery append script
  Passes: <input type="text" name="passes[]">
  Points: <input type="text" name="points[]">
  Passes: <input type="text" name="passes[]">
  Points: <input type="text" name="points[]">
```

Controller:

```
//Loops through a table like form for inputting stats
function add_stat() {
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($this->input->post('points') as $points) {
     $dataSet1[$i++] = array (
          'points' => $points
     );
   }

   foreach ($this->input->post('passes') as $passes) {
     $dataSet2[$i++] = array (
           'passes' => $passses
     );
   }
 //Not sure how to pass multiple arrays, or if even possible
 $this->sport_model->insert_stat($dataSet1, $dataSet2);
 }
```

Model:

```
//Passing multiple params error out due to "String to Array Conversion"
function insert_stat($dataSet1, $dataSet2) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('table', $dataSet1, $dataSet2);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set your controller and model as:

controller:

```
//Loops through a table like form for inputting stats
function add_stat() {

   $points = $this->input->post('points');
   $passes = $this->input->post('passes'); 
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($points);$i++)
   {
     $dataSet[$i] = array ('points' => $points[$i], 'passes' => $passses[$i]);
   }
   // $dataSet is an array of array
   $this->sport_model->insert_stat($dataSet);
 }
```

model:

```
function insert_stat($dataSet)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('table', $dataSet);
    return $this->db->insert_id(); // this will return the id of last item inserted.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, insert_batch() only takes two params: the table name and a data set.

Second, insert_id() isn't going to do you much good on a batch insert, but that's not a huge deal.

I assume you want points and passes to be in the same record, and that you're appending another set of points/passes inputs via JS.

View:

```
Passes: <input type="text" name="scores[0][passes]">
Points: <input type="text" name="scores[0][points]">
Passes: <input type="text" name="scores[1][passes]">
Points: <input type="text" name="scores[1][points]">
// etc...
```

In your controller, you would then just use one $dataSet array and loop through `$this->input->post('scores')`

When $dataSet is complete, you'd batch insert with `$this->db->insert_batch('table', $dataSet)`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I changed the name attribute, however, I'm still receiving an array to string error
`var points = document.createElement('input');`        
`setAttributes(points, {"name": "scores[][points]", "id": "points", "value": "0"});`